# Could someone explain what this code does please?

Tags: haskell

Could someone explain what this code does, please?

```
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]
primes = [x| x <- [1..], length (factors x) == 2]
```

Comment: Could you narrow down your question to a specific part you don't understand? If you're completely new to Haskell, you should start with a tutorial. There's a bunch of things going on in those two terse lines.

Comment: The code doesn't do anything, there is no IO.

Comment: First line (function) returns factors of given number n, for example for for 7 it would be 1 and 7, for 9 - 1, 3, 9. Second line returns infinite list of primes, checking if number of factors equals two (1 and the number itself). Play with it inside ghci and you would know how it works.

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension

Answer (score 5):

The first line of your code defines a function called `factors` which takes an argument `n`, presumably an `Int`, and returns a list of elements, defined by a comprehension list.

List comprehensions are syntactic sugar that Haskell provides for you to define lists in, at least to me, a clearer an elegant way.

Basically, they have this pattern:

```
[ elements | generators and predicates ]
```

Where generators are expressions of the form `x <- collection` and predicates are boolean expressions. Each expression/predicate on the right side of the `|` is separated either by a comma or by another `|`, which means you could have more than one generator in the same list comprehension. Generators serve as a way of take/generate elements from specific collections, where predicates act as filters.

An easy example:

```
[ x + 1 | x <- [1, 2, 3], x == 2 ]
```

will result in

```
[3]
```

The generator `x <- [1, 2, 3]` says, take each element from `[1, 2, 3]`, and the predicate `x == 2` states: but only those who accomplish this `x == 2`, which means the only value that the `generators and predicates` expression returns is `2`. Then, `elements` is `x` but `+ 1`, so we result in `3`.

Let's recap your first line of code:

```
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]
```

Well, the left hand side of the `=` is clear, it's a function called `factors` that takes `n` as an argument, right? And in the right hand side, what do we have? Yes, a list comprehension!

Let's analyze it, remembering the form:

```
[ form of the elements | generators and predicates ]
```

It seems that we have `x` as the structure of the elements, and we have two expressions on the right hand side of the `|`.

The first one

```
x <- [1..n]
```

is a... generator! It basically says, take the `x`s from this collection `[1..n]` (which is the list from 1 to `n`, the parameter given).

The second one

```
n `mod` x == 0
```

is a... predicate! It states that the elements we are going to put as a result, must verify this condition: the remainder of `n` divided by `x` is `0`.

All in all, what `factors n` function does is to calculate the list of numbers from `1` to `n` which exactly divide `n`, that is, the list of `n` divisors (factors).

Now, I think you will be able to analyze and say what `primes` does by yourself.